# Taking files in Folder A from Folder B

Tags: windows-10, public-folders

How can I select the file names in folder A from Folder B?

For example

Folder A has files
`1,2,6,7.`

Folder B has files `1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10`

So I need to only select files that are in folder A `1,2,6,7` from folder B.

I have about 1K + files in folder B, but only require the ones listed in Folder A, which is less than 1k. But I don't want to have to select files from Folder B one by one according to the files in Folder A.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by select? The question title says 'Taking'. Do you want to copy the files? Move?

Comment: @Jelphy If possible I would like to move the files I need from Folder B to Folder C. I don't know how copying works? Would the "copied" files be saved in memory as in I can just cntrl+v to a folder of my choice?

Comment: that is one way of doing it. I would probably use `Windows PowerShell` for this task, unless someone has a better solution.

Comment: How would I use PowerShell to achieve this? I'm not firmiliar with any commands and what not to execute it.

Comment: You could try and ask this question on the SO `PowerShell` forum, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/powershell - if you show some effort someone might help :)

Comment: Ah ok thanks, and I've been actually spending the last few hours find the files 1 by 1 from a pool of 9k files and I'm just at the point where I think there has to be a better way to do this.

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out.

I used `dir D:\Game\Cap /s /b > D:\Game\Cap\list.txt`

to make a list of the files I needed. I then move that list.txt into folder B

and ran this script I found online:

```
@echo off
REM BATCH file Created by NEUTRON16 (sevenforums.com)
CLS
REM CHECK FOR ADMIN RIGHTS
COPY /b/y NUL %WINDIR%\06CF2EB6-94E6-4a60-91D8-AB945AE8CF38 >NUL 2>&1
IF ERRORLEVEL 1 GOTO:NONADMIN
DEL %WINDIR%\06CF2EB6-94E6-4a60-91D8-AB945AE8CF38 >NUL 2>&1
:ADMIN
REM GOT ADMIN RIGHTS
COLOR 1F
ECHO Hi, %USERNAME%!
ECHO Please wait...
for /f "usebackq delims=" %%a in ("%~dp0list.txt") do echo d |xcopy "%%a" "D:\Game\Bin" /e /i
COLOR 2F
ECHO.
ECHO BATCH file Created by Neutron16 (sevenforums.com)
PAUSE
GOTO:EOF
:NONADMIN
REM NO ADMIN RIGHTS
COLOR 4F
ECHO.
ECHO PLEASE RUN AS ADMINISTRATOR
ECHO.
pause
GOTO:EOF
```

And it worked!

Answer (score 0):

For this,
1. You will need the full path names of Folder A:
You need to go to Folder A, click on the Address bar and copy the full path

It will be something like C:\foldername\foldername2\foldername3

2. Copy the full path of Destination folder using the above described method.
   Now you need to Open **Command prompt**:
   and type

move **pathtofolderA**\*.* pathtodestinationfolder

Example:
move C:\user\documents\*.* C:\user\downloads\

I think the path is Case-sensitive some one can correct me ..

**Edit**: Batch file

```
    for %f in (c:\pathtofolderA\*) do copy c:\pathtofolderB\%f c:\destinationpath
```

Comment: this moves the files from folder A, question asks how to move the files from folder B, which are also exist in folder A.

Comment: @MátéJuhász See edit. Hope it helps.